# Every tangent vector is the velocity vector of some curve

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

This is Proposition 8.16 from Tu's book *An Introduction to Manifolds*.

> For any point $p$ in a Manifold $M$ and any tangent vector $X_p \in T_pM$, there are $\epsilon > 0$ and a smooth curve $c: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \rightarrow M$ such that $c(0) = p$ and $c'(0) = X_p$.

His proof (in terms of notation, Tu uses the the subscript $*$ to indicate the differential and $'$ to indicate the velocity vector):

> Let $(U, \phi) = (U, x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ be a chart centered at $p$;
> i.e. $\phi(p) = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $X_p = \sum a^i
>  \partial/\partial x^i|_p$ at $p$. Let $r^1, \ldots, r^n$ be the
> standard coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $x^i = r^i \circ \phi$.
> To find a curve $c$ at $p$ with $c'(0) = X_p$, start with a curve
> $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\alpha(0) = 0$ and $\alpha'(0) = \sum
>  a^i \partial/\partial r^i|_0$. We then map $\alpha$ to $M$ via
> $\phi^{-1}$. By Proposition 8.15 (which says the velocity of a curve
> in local coordinates is $c'(t) = \sum \dot{c}^i(t) \partial/\partial
>  x^i |_{c(t)}$ relative to the basis $\{\partial/\partial x^i|_p\}$),
> the simplest such $\alpha$ is $$\alpha(t) = (a^1 t, \ldots, a^n t),
>  \quad t \in (\epsilon, \epsilon)$$ where $\epsilon$ is sufficnetly
> small that $\alpha(t)$ lies in $\phi(U)$. Define $c = \phi^{-1} \circ
>  \alpha: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \rightarrow M$. Then  $$c(0) =
>  \phi^{-1}(\alpha(0)) = \phi^{-1}(0) = p$$ and by Proposition 8.8
> $$c'(0) = (\phi^{-1})_*\alpha_*\Big(\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t = 0}\Big) =
>  (\phi^{-1})_*\Big(\sum a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial r^i}\Big|_0\Big) =
>  \sum a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p = X_p.$$

I am stuck on the last line of this proof. Proposition 8.8 says

> Let $(U, \phi) = (U, x^1, \ldots, x^n)$ be a chart about a point $p$ in a manifold $M$. Then $$\phi_*\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p\Big) = \frac{\partial}{\partial r^i}\Big|_{\phi(p)}.$$

My interpretation of the above proposition is that the differential $\phi_*$ maps the $i$th basis vector of the tangent space of the domain to the $i$th basis vector of the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^n$. How does he use this to conclude that
$$(\phi^{-1})_*\alpha_*\Big(\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t = 0}\Big) =
 (\phi^{-1})_*\Big(\sum a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial r^i}\Big|_0\Big) =
 \sum a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p?$$
For example, how does he conclude that
$$\alpha_*\Big(\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t = 0}\Big) = \sum a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial r^i}\Big|_0$$
and likewise for $(\phi^{-1})_*$? Where are these summations coming from? I'm guessing it comes from a chain-rule type of argument, but this is only my intuition from $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I am not sure if this is correct for an arbitrary manifold.

Comment: hi! the various $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ are a basis of the tangent space. the equation is a vector equation and the $a_i$ are the components of the velocity vector in the base. hope this helps!

Comment: @l4teLearner Thank you for your comment. I am wondering how $d/dt$, the only basis vector in the tangent space of the domain of $\alpha$, gets mapped to a *sum* of basis vectors when the proposition I mentioned (8.8) suggests mapping a single basis vector to a single basis vector.

Comment: proposition 8.8 refers to the differential of the "diffeomorphism" $\phi$ which is as you said the mapping of each coordinate into a coordinate of $\mathbb{R}$. it maps each coordinate function to its value _by definition_. $\alpha$ instead, is a curve, and it is one dimensional, but its tangent vector has to be represented in the tangent space, which has a basis of $n$ vectors. it's just the decomposition of a vector in a basis, there is nothing a priori that maps a basis vector to a basis vector. even if this was the case, you could choose a different chart and it would no longer hold.

Comment: @l4teLearner That really helps, I think I got it now, thank you!

Comment: I am glad to help, I commented as I studied Tu too (no pun intended). that book is great, it really opened my mind (and grinded it a bit). can't wait to start his book on differential geometry.

Comment: @CBBAM You should now write an answer to your own question.

Comment: @PaulFrost You are right, I have posted an answer just now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments of l4teLearner I was able to figure out this question. The tangent space of the curve $\alpha: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is $n$-dimensional. This is why the differential $\alpha_*$, a map to and from tangent spaces, outputs a linear combination of $n$ basis vectors.